# Sparse Principal Component Analysis

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I'd like to run [sparse PCA](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/spc_jcgs.pdf) on some economic data. There appear to be several R functions available including [elasticnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elasticnet/elasticnet.pdf) and [PMA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PMA/PMA.pdf) but I wanted to check if anyone had something coded up directly in MMA they might be willing share?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: Did you give `RLink` a try? Its meant for such purpose where you can mix and use existing R code/library on the fly from your Mathematica code.

Comment: @PlatoManiac Thanks, yes intend to use RLink if no MMA code available. Wanted to check if MMA version available so I might have more control over algo and diagnostics.